# Fit line similar to power of trendline in Excel

Tags: fitting

Is there a way to fit a line similar to `power` trendline in Excel?

Something in this fashion: `Fit[data, {1, x, x^(-n)}, x]`

EDIT:

```
modelFit = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*x^n, {a, n}, x];

Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[modelFit[x], {x, 10, 300}]
 ]
```

Gives a result which is a little off:

[image]

Data:

```
data = {{10, 0.229456252}, {11, 0.197084485}, {12, 0.190385018}, {13, 
0.167211837}, {14, 0.162024048}, {15, 0.146360843}, {16, 
0.141582714}, {17, 0.128658408}, {18, 0.12634757}, {19, 
0.115664973}, {20, 0.112934492}, {21, 0.103436493}, {22, 
0.101525578}, {23, 0.094280256}, {24, 0.093998465}, {25, 
0.087612133}, {26, 0.085961964}, {27, 0.081235224}, {28, 
0.079490311}, {29, 0.075953893}, {30, 0.073722495}, {31, 
0.070194375}, {32, 0.069373963}, {33, 0.066115294}, {34, 
0.064971653}, {35, 0.061982956}};
```

Comment: Use the same function if you want the same result: something like `NonlinearModelFit[data, a + b x + c x^n, {a,b,c,n}, x];`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does your data represent?

Comment: @Szabolcs, variance of scores in a computer boardgame.

Comment: can you explain in what way the data is a little off?

Comment: @jensen, im not sure if my screenshot is clear enough, but the  line does not go through the first points in the upper bound of the graph.

Comment: oh, I see the problem now. So the fit is ok, just the plotting does not work right. You didn't post the whole data, that is why it looks better in the answers posted (it has to do with the plot range).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Try e.g. `data = Transpose[{Range[10], Range[10]^3}]` and then use `NonlinearModelFit[data, x^n, {n}, x]`. As bill s said, read for more details Mathematicas help regarding `NonlinearModelFit`.

For your data you can use:

```
fitFkt = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*x^n, {a, n}, x]
fitFkt["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable", ConfidenceLevel -> .95]
```

The result is the same as within Excel (`y = 2.3409x^-1.018`; you only forgot the factor `a`) as you can see from:

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[fitFkt[x], {x, 10, 35}]]
```

[image: Fit to data]

Comment: I have updated my post with an example im working on. The fitted line is a bit off.

Comment: Could you please give us the data too? Then we could try to get a better fit.

Comment: Sure, i can give a small sample. Excel fits it perfectly to a power trendline.

Comment: Thanks for the great example. What i dont understand is that my fitted line does not begin from 10 as my points. I need to enter something like `{-2000,300,x}` which seems ok. I have updated the example with my issue.

Comment: I wrote that sentence all wrong, its ofcourse not OK, its very unusual and strange.

Comment: Ok, just to summarize: The fit is ok, just the plot not. Do you agree? That is because you plot over a big range. If you use `Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[modelFit[x], {x, 10, 300}, PlotRange -> All]]` you will see that the function fits to the data (without choosing such a big range as above). By the way: If you do not trust your fit, you can use something like `Table[{i, modelFit[i]}, {i, 10, 30}]`. If you compare the result with your data (or calculate the residual), you will see that the fit is well.

Comment: that did the trick, thanks alot. Is there a way to move the y-axis to 0 instead of 50.

Comment: Do you mean the axis origin? If yes, try something such as `Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[modelFit[x], {x, 10, 300}, PlotRange -> All], 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`. If this does not solve your problem, could you please describe it more detailed?

Comment: exactly what i needed, now its perfect!

Comment: Great to hear! If you need more help, do not hesitate to ask ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Plot automatically reduces the `Plot` range depending on the function that is plotted. Adding `PlotRange->All` shows the function completely in the `Plot` plot. Show uses the data range from the first plot that is shown, so you eventually need to add a `PlotRange->All` inside the `Show` command (depending on your data).

```
modelFit = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*x^n, {a, n}, x];

Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[modelFit[x], {x, 10, 300}, PlotRange->All]
]
```

[image]

---

#### An advice for plotting and fitting power laws:

Often it is better to take the logarithm of the function and the data, or to use a logarithmic scale (`LogLogPlot` or `ListLogLogPlot`).

Let's say you have $f(x)=a\cdot x^n$, taking the logarithm leads to:
$$\log(f(x)) = \log(a) + n \cdot \log(x)$$
so you basically get a straight line if you plot $\log(f(x))$ vs. $\log(x)$ and the slope is the exponent $n$. This makes it easier to see deviations.

```
Show[ListPlot[Log@data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  Plot[Log@modelFit[Exp@x], {x, 1, 4}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"log(score)", "log(Var)"}, 
  BaseStyle -> {14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the model is linear, you can use `LinearModelFit`. If the model is nonlinear, then `NonlinearModelFit`. To see how to apply these, check out the help (F1 on the word LinearModelFit`) where there are plenty of examples.

To mimic the function you've included, you could try something like:

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, a + b x + c x^n, {a,b,c,n}, x];
```

Though it also looks like an exponential decay, so you might want to see how that fits as well.